# c# - get multiple listbox values and turn into comma separated string winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to get all the selected list items in my listbox and put their values into a comma separated string. I populate the listbox using a List containing my custom object TestSubject which contains a TestSubjectID and TestSubjectName:

```
var objTestSubjectList = new List<TestSubject>();
//code that adds items to List
```

I then map the Listbox datasource to this list and set the DisplayMember, ValueMember correspondingly:

```
lbTestSubjects.DataSource = objTestSubjectList;
lbTestSubjects.DisplayMember = "TestSubjectName";
lbTestSubjects.ValueMember = "TestSubjectID";
```

When the multiple items in the listbox have been selected, I want to grab the values for each item (the TestSubjectID) and place them in a comma separated string. For example, if 3 items are selected with TestSubjectIDs of 10 20 and 30 I want to loop through and grab the values and put them in a string like so: "10,20,30". I am using windows forms. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the [SelectedIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices(v=vs.110).aspx) collection, retrieve the TestSubject object stored in the Item corresponding to the index selected and then add its TestSubjectID value to a list of integers. Finally [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) will create the string for you.

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
foreach(int x in lbTestSubjects.SelectedIndices)
{
    TestSubject t = lbTestSubjects.Items[x] as TestSubject ;
    ids.Add(t.TestSubjectID);
}
string result = string.Join(",", ids);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This code could also be reduced a lot using LINQ

```
var ri = lbTestSubjects.SelectedIndices
                       .OfType<int>()
                       .Select(i => ((TestSubject)lbTestSubjects.Items[i]).TestSubjectID);
string result = string.Join(",", ri);
```